# Dynamically populating an iOS table view with Swift from an API

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, api, mobile-application

I'm currently in the process of creating an app to display the latest football scores. I've connected to an API through a URL and pulled back the team names for the english premier league into an array of strings.

The problem seems to come from populating the iOS table view that I intend to display the list of teams with. The data appears to be pulled from the API fine, but for some reason the TableView method which creates a cell and returns it doesn't seem to be called. The only time I can get the method to be called is when I actually hard code a value into the array of team names.

Here is my code:

```
class Main: UIViewController {

    var names = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let URL_String = "https://football-api.com/api/?Action=standings&APIKey=[API_KEY_REMOVED]&comp_id=1204"

        let url = NSURL(string: URL_String)

        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

                if let teams = json["teams"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    for team in teams {
                        if let name = team["stand_team_name"] as? String {
                            self.names.append(name)
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch {
                print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }



    // Number of Sections In Table
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Number of Rows in each Section
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    // Sets the content of each cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

}
```

Just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction here. This code doesn't crash or throw any errors, it just refuses to load a table view. The only reason I can possibly think of is that the array of team names is empty after completing a request to the API. However I've set breakpoints throughout and checked the values of local variables and the desired information is being pulled from the API as intended...

Comment: You should reload the table view once you have new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are in the correct way , just refresh the table using `reloadData` once you got the new data from API

```
if let teams = json["teams"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                for team in teams {
                    if let name = team["stand_team_name"] as? String {
                        self.names.append(name)
                    }
                }

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.yourtableViewname.reloadData()
})
  }
```

Comment: just remember that you always have to make a call to the main queue ( as @Anbu did) if you're updating the user interface from a background queue

Comment: @Russell `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is the main queue

Comment: it's worth reinforcing the point that @Abnu has demonstrated here - just remember that you always have to make a call to the main queue `dispatch_get_main_queue() ` if you're updating the user interface from a background queue